# Prevent SLIME to switch to the repl buffer

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime, dot-emacs

I never really use the REPL and I find annoying that it pops up every time I connect to a swank instance. How can I prevent SLIME to switch to the repl buffer?

I tried to find where it does that in slime's code, but it's kind of huge when you're not sure what to look for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I've done it in [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy):

```
(defun lispy--eval-lisp (str)
  "Eval STR as Common Lisp code."
  (require 'slime-repl)
  (unless (slime-current-connection)
    (let ((wnd (current-window-configuration)))
      (slime)
      (while (not (and (slime-current-connection)
                       (get-buffer-window (slime-output-buffer))))
        (sit-for 0.2))
      (set-window-configuration wnd)))
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (cadr (slime-eval `(swank:eval-and-grab-output ,str)))))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are simply saving the current window configuration and restoring it after the connection?
Also, nice try at plublicizing your project :P

Comment: You make it sound so easy. It took me hours to come up with that:(

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't my intention to make it sound easy, I just wasn't sure if it was what the code was doing :)

Comment: I was just joking. Btw, the `sit-for` is only because I can't eval until slime is completely initialized,
and it takes a while to do it.

Comment: That's what I thought, and it's also why I kept it there. Thanks.

Comment: I created an issue in slime to help having a less hacky solution: https://github.com/slime/slime/issues/645

Answer (score 1):

Here was my solution, thanks to @abo-abo's answer.

```
(defun my-slime-connect () (interactive)
   (let ((wnd (current-window-configuration)))
 (call-interactively 'slime-connect)
 (sit-for 0.2) ;; Not sure if necessary, haven't tested without it.
 (set-window-configuration wnd)))
```